# groovy Object and primitive confusion

Tags: groovy

Here's a part of (groovy) class that stores some data in Mongodb:

```
long save(Object data) {

    def customerReference = getNextCustomerReference()

    def map = ['customerReference': customerReference, 'data': data, 'created': new Date()]

    BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject(map)
    collection.insert(basicDBObject)
    customerReference
}

private long getNextCustomerReference() {
    1234
}
```

even though I have explicitly said i want a primitive long, what ends up in the database is an object:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52f3c0597d844b0fcee29013"), "customerReference" : NumberLong(1234), "data" : "original data", "created" : ISODate("2014-02-06T17:03:21.411Z") }
```

However, if I change the return type to def for the private method this happens:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52f3c1477d84698725f50fe5"), "customerReference" : 1234, "data" : "data", "created" : ISODate("2014-02-06T17:07:19.055Z") }
```

which the behaviour I want (a primitive stored in the db).

Can someone explain this because its baffling. Surely if I go out of my way to define a type, Groovy should try and honour it?

Comment: What if you do `long customerReference = getNextCustomerReference()`?

Comment: goes in as an Object. Even more weird, if I do that AND make the return type on the method def, it goes in as an Object.

Comment: What if you skip the `BasicDBObject` and go straight for `collection.insert( map )`? I think that's allowed

Comment: (assuming you're using GMongo)

Comment: I'm not using any third party mapping tools and i dont want to at this stage. This question is more about Groovy than Mongodb anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy almost always automatically autoboxes primitive types to their number reference type-equivalent:

```
long test_long() { 123l }
int test_int() { 123 }
def test_def() { 123 }
def test_def_long() { 123l }

long l = 42l

assert test_long().class == Long.class
assert test_int().class == Integer.class
assert test_def().class == Integer.class
assert test_def_long().class == Long.class
assert l.class === Long.class
```

If you remove the `long` return type, the object is autoboxed to `java.lang.Integer`. Seems your code handles the `Integer` like a "primitive".

Some time ago [Groovy 1.8 introduced primitive type optimization](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy+1.8+release+notes), an internal fallback to use primitive types under the hood in certain situations. This can help in some situations but is an internal performance optimization you can't directly make use of (by using some syntax construct or something like that).

Sometimes you can force a primitive by an explicit cast, but chances are high it will be converted to a reference type along the way through methods calls and stuff.